# Javascript SubForm Not Displaying Success Pop Up Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Built a form with HTML, CSS, Javascript linked to a Google Sheet. Built in VSCode.

TWO QUESTIONS:

1/ A pop-up box is supposed to pop up on form submission saying "Application Submitted!" if filled out with required fields. The pop-up box is not showing up -- but the data is being processed into the linked Google Sheet. The application instead just reloads.

2/ If filled out incorrectly, a pop-up box is supposed to pop up saying "Error!". However, even if filled out incorrectly, the data is being processed into the linked Google Sheet without this pop-up (and then reloading the page like above). It's like the Javascript is overriding the HTML code such as requiring email to be in an email format, etc.?? The HTML worked prior to writing in the Javascript linking to the Google Sheet.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function SubForm (){
    $.ajax({
        url:'[NOTE: URL IS HERE]',
        type:'post',
        data:$("#survey-form").serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
          alert("Application Submitted!")
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Error!")
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

ALSO THE HTML FOR THE BUTTON:

```
<button onclick="SubForm()" class="btn submit" type="submit" value="Let's Bop!" />Let's Bop!</button>
```

Comment: remove the `function ()` from success and error. just use alert

Comment: hmmm removed both, but still not seeing the pop up...

Comment: delete your cache (ctrl+f5), that might help. I've never worked with google forms, so I'm just guessing :/ sry. otherwise your ajax looks good

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to observe here.

First,

Let's see what is the form action? or the `action=""` part of your form? Since you are using a button `type='submit'` and assuming this is inside your form, the form will submit and perform the action part.

If this is the case then you need your form to stop doing default behavior on submit so that the page stays and give time to your ajax to finish up so that alert can appear.

Second,

Let the form handle onSubmit, and remove onClick from the button as it is a submit button let it submit the form, but handle the onsubmit event. Even in this case, we will have to stop the form to perform its default behavior.

Here is a codepen you can refer https://codepen.io/vbrmnd/pen/eYjbRgw